# Why do I have two Guest Users?

Tags: macos, guest-account, hacking

I'm kind of worried about the macOS (10.13 High Sierra) installed on my computer. I restarted my computer because it was misbehaving with Reminders (I logged out and in to iCloud to see if Continuity would start working again and it caused some trouble). When the login window appeared I saw a Guest User which I had deactivated before. I then logged in and it was still disabled. I enabled it and restarted and now I have two Guest Users ... only the one on the left asks for a password. I might have been hacked, don't know though...

Some possibly connected information:

- I installed macports (reinstalled to the latest version)
- I installed gnupg using macports
- I ran geth (Ethereum client) (no sudo)
- I played with iCloud (log out and in)
- My HD is encrypted so I get the login before booting

[image: Two Guest Users]

**Edit 2017-10-06 14:23:36**:

- I turned off Firevault, I clicked the button and there was no turning around.
- I installed update 'macOS High Sierra 10.13 (17A405)' ([link](https://developer.apple.com/news/releases/?id=10052017a))
- I restarted and the multiple user login was gone
- I turned on Find my Mac and restarted... the double, nay, triple (my own account + 2 other) login was there but what I see is a little bit different.

[image: One Guest user and now a Other... User]

**Edit 2017-10-06 16:07:34**:

- I was able to hide the "Other..." login option by disabling the [root login](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204012) (System Preferences->Users & Groups->Unlock (bottom left)->Login Options->Join->Open Directory Utility->in Directory Utility Unlock (bottom left)->In Edit Menu, select Disable Root User)
- When I enable Guest User, the root user gets enabled.
- When using the Guest User and then login out, the computer freezes into a black screen with the pointer.

[image: Black screen with pointer]

Comment: not a solution but have you considered backing up your data and just starting from scratch ie> boot into recovery and reinstall. i mean this sounds strange, i dont know if i'd trust it without formatting.

Comment: I have the same problem. Now I can remove Guest User and Root User but The problem of **freeze & black screen after Mac sleep still exist**. When I press any button, the screen turn on and the pointer appear for second then turn off right away. Sometime the screen has **distort colour** (now and even before the freeze problem occurs). I think that could be a problem, Apple made for High Sierra :-( I'll restore to the backup 2 days ago then I'll let you know if that's work. If anyone know how to fix that, please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The one guest account with a proper picture is an OS account - you can remove it from the FileVault startup screen with this command.

Enter the following command in the Terminal:

```
sudo fdesetup remove -user Guest
```

That guest account is still around, but it’s not the one that comes from Find My Mac and FileVault - that’s the one with the shady silhouette - you can disable that by turning off Find My Mac or going to the user accounts preference pane in system preferences and electing the guest account configuration you prefer.

[image]

Comment: This actually works. fdesetup is the command line file vault configuration tool and the mentioned command removes the user "Guest" from file vault. After running the command the Guest account with the distorted icon disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. I have the same issue with High Sierra and the icon is corrupted too.
MacOS has two types of a Guest user:

- An actual (but restricted) user account.
  It can access files and apps, so it can’t be used on an encrypted disk.
- A special mode that a computer reboots into.
  It can only use Safari.

For some reason Guest user account shows up on the login screen even though it can’t log in due to encryption.

I’ve just deleted the Guest account and it no longer shows up:

- Open Terminal app
- Paste this text:

  `sudo dscl . delete /Users/Guest`
- Type Admin password and press Enter

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. Do you have some link saying this is a bug? Is there a bug report?

Comment: I did a reinstall, and this _bug_ is gone... it might not be a _bug_ still I think it would still bother me not to do a clean install knowing that this went wrong and not knowing why...

Answer (score 0):

At least with 10.13.2, I found that disabling the guest account from System Preferences, rebooting, then re-enabling it does the trick.